# Phrase or word for concept of incorporation of individual preferences into single final product

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, expression-choice

What phrase or word suggestions come to mind for the concept of selecting a group of individual preferences to be incorporated into the production of a single finished product?  For instance, when buying a new car, one would determine a list of individual preferences of color, equipment, accessories, etc. to be incorporated within the car that will be purchased.

Comment: "Options", "customization", "personalization" ?

Comment: "Specify", or "specification"? I might specify metallic paint and cloth upholstery in my next car.

Comment: Design?  6moretogo

Comment: Or (especially in UK) *bespoke*.